# How can I display a totals heading in SSRS when there is a column grouping? (It should appear on just the last item in the group)

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to include some text for a heading at the bottom of a column in an SSRS report, but the problem is that the heading is being repeated for every group item in the column, but I only want it to appear in the last one.

---

To give an example, imagine a report that should look something like this:

```
Day   |     Company     | Total Income
       TestInc  OtherLtd
Mon      £5        £9          £14
Tue      £4        £4          £8
Wed      £8        £2          £10
                 Total:        £32
```

The raw data comes from a SQL table that has entries for each transaction for each company. The report groups the transactions by day for each row, and then by company for the columns. There could be many more days, and many more companies to be shown.

The total income column shows the totals for each row. (So the total income on any given day). And the final total at the bottom is the total income for the all companies and all days.

<sub>(This is a slightly contrived example just to simplify for the purposes of the question, so it may seem like I can just alter the layout to fix the problem, but in reality that isn't an option)</sub>

My problem is with the positing of the "Total:" text. It's in a cell which is in the column group, so currently it is appearing like this:

```
Day   |     Company     | Total Income
       TestInc  OtherLtd
Mon      £5        £9          £14
Tue      £4        £4          £8
Wed      £8        £2          £10
       Total:    Total:        £32
```

I've tried using an expression for hiding the cell like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!CompanyId.Value = Last(Fields!CompanyId.Value, "Companies"), False, True)
```

But the 'Last' function seems to return the value from the last row in the query result, rather than the last company in the group which is what I need to check against.

**Is there any way I can have a cell in a column group, that isn't actually a part of the grouping and only appears at the end? Or failing that, some improved expression that lets me hide it for all but the last column in the group?**

Comment: What are the values in the cells before you run the report? Can't you just delete 1 of the cells in 1 of the columns?

Comment: An easy fix would be to put the label in the box with the total, like ="Total: " & sum(myDataset!income.value). It wouldn't look exactly like your example but might work for your need.

Comment: @WEI_DBA The two columns "TestInc" and "OtherLtd" are a single column that is grouped by company name. In the report design view there is only one "Total:" cell, it just gets repeated at run time for each company in the data. So there doesn't seem to be any way to just delete one of them. (It's also entirely possible that this report will be run with more than two companies)

Comment: @SpencerKershaw That would work in this example, but this is oversimplified to make it easy to explain. In the actual report there are multiple total columns that total slightly different things, and it's not acceptable to the users to have a "total:" text in each one (mainly because it would cause there to be a lot of wasted space).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, since the **Company** column is repeating for the column Group whatever you put in the field will also repeating.

If you sort your query the same as you are sorting the Group in the table, you should be able to use your expression to only show it once:

```
=IIF(Fields!CompanyId.Value = LAST(Fields!CompanyId.Value, "Companies"), "Total:", "")
```

Why don't you move **Total** under your **Days** and **SUM** the individual companies too? You'd be like **Microsoft** - turning something that doesn't work right into a "**feature**".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hannover, but unfortunately I might have oversimplified for the question. In the actual report there is actual two levels of column grouping and the sort order of the query is required to be on unrelated fields for other reasons so I can't do that.

Also, in reply to your second solution it's not actually company income in the real report, and the data that it is wouldn't make any sense to sum, so that's not acceptable to the users.

I'll up-vote you anyway as I appreciate the ideas.